# Where can I find the yum repos files for centos 4.7 i386?

Tags: centos, yum

Does anyone know where I can find the i386 centos 4.7 repos files that would normally sit in /etc/yum.repos.d.   Alas, it looks like someone copied the 5.5 edition over to a 4.7 system.

I can setup a new VM, install 4.7 and extract the files from that system (but I was hoping for a faster approach.

Please let me know if you know where these files live on the net.  I'm off to RPMfind to see what I can locate.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be in this RPM: http://vault.centos.org/4.7/os/i386/CentOS/RPMS/centos-release-4-7.i386.rpm